# How can I log user who create entity in symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Lets say I have few entities: Article, Tag, Comment and I would like to save information about who created it. Sure I can add OneToMany connection to all of them but that does not scale too much. How is this solved in larger projects?

Comment: Have a look at the `blameable` extension in the https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions library.

Comment: I know doctrine extensions but never noticed Blameable. Thanks for pointing it out. It should do the job nicely.

Comment: There is also the same thing in the `DoctrineBehavious` (https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#blameable) but I haven't used them.